# What is the physiological mechanism for getting unconscious after a punch to the head?

Tags: physiology, neurophysiology

It is the everyday life in boxing: One boxer gets a smack in the head, cannot do anything for many seconds and then: Victory of his opponent due to a Knockout!

What is the reason for losing consciousness for a short time by e.g. a strong smack in the head?

Are there any neuronal reactions that cause this?

Comment: Does [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10351/mechanical-cause-of-loss-of-consciousness) answer your question?

Comment: The answers are differing from each other; is it due to the Neuron compression or because the blood flow is truncated after a punch?

Comment: Yes, questions often yield different answers. Both answers may, or may not be correct. If the question is the same as yours, and you wish more answers, you can put a bounty on the previous question. I'm marking this as a dupe.